# Is it possible to fill a hidden field's value with a php function in an AMP Form

Tags: javascript, php, amp-html

So I have an amp form and I need it to capture all of the users background information (like utm_source, geolocation, campaign information etc) So normally I would accomplish this with hidden fields filled by javascript but amp doesn't let me have javascript so my next thought would be fill them with a function in the value section like so:

```
<input name="location" type="hidden" value="<?php getGeoByIP()?>">
```

But this isn't working on my amp form. I did some research and I think my answer lies within amp's variable substitutions but I read through the documentation most of it was in reference to amp lists and I'm still not sure how I would accomplish this.

Any help or guidance would be great, thank you!

Comment: when you look at the source in the browser, what do you see for that element?

Comment: right click on the input and select "Inspect Element" from the menu. Is the value attribute filled out, and if so with what? That's what Jaromanda X is asking...

Comment: @jaromanda-x <input name="location" type="hidden" value="">

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - but you have to tackle it another way.
HTML:

```
<input name="location" value="{MY_PLACEHOLDER}" />
```

On PHP end:

```
<?php 
$userInfo = $getTheInfos();  // GET THE INFOS YOU WANT
$template = file_get_contents('my_template.html'); // YOUR HTML
$output  = str_replace('{MY_PLACEHOLDER}',$userInfo, $template);
echo $output;
```